# converting puppet erb template to epp

Tags: templates, puppet

I'm trying to convert erb templates to epp (new company policy) and there isn't a lot of documentation on epp yet.
Here's what i have in erb:

```
    <% filter.select{|x| x != 'filtertype'}.sort.each do |key, element| -%>
    <%= key %>: '<%= element %>'
    <% end -%>
```

it works great! however i have to find the equivalent for epp.  I can get the "each" part to work, but the select method isn't working for me.

I'm stumped!

I tried something like:

```
    <% $filter.select { |$x| $x != 'filtertype'}.each |$key, $element| { -%>
    <%= $key %>: '<%= $element %>'  
    <% } -%>
```

this in particular errors on '|' for the $x.

I also tried:

```
    <% $filter.select  |$x| {$x != 'filtertype'}.each |$key, $element| { -%>
    <%= $key %>: '<%= $element %>'  
    <% } -%>
```

but that gives me something like "Error while evaluating a Method call, select(): Wrong number of arguments given 1 for 3"

I've tried moving around the {}   and changing them to (), but no luck.

does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have to go with something that varies from the ERB version a bit more, but it's hard to give you a confident recommendation without a [mcve].  You've a bit overdone the "minimal" part, at the expense of "complete" and "verifiable".  At minimum, I'd like to see an example definition of the `$filter` variable's value and a corresponding desired template output.

Comment: `select()` isn't a built-in function, where does it come from? Can you show the source code so we understand what it does? (https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_iteration.html#list-of-iteration-functions, perhaps you want `filter()`)

Answer (score 1):

As Dominic Cleal mentions in the comment, `select()` is not a Puppet function, however `filter()` is and is the equivalent of `select` in Ruby.

Therefore:

Given a class:

```
class foo () {

  # Some test data.
  $filter = {
    'filtertype' => 'foo',
    'apples'     => 1,
    'bananas'    => 2,
  }

  # How to declare the ERB template for comparison:
  file { '/foo':
    ensure  => file,
    content => template('foo/mytemplate.erb'),
  }

  # How to declare the EPP template for comparison:
  file { '/bar':
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp('foo/mytemplate.epp', {'filter' => $filter}),
  }
}
```

Content of the ERB file exactly as given in the question:

```
<% @filter.select{|x| x != 'filtertype'}.sort.each do |key, element| -%>
<%= key %>: '<%= element %>'
<% end -%>
```

Content of an equivalent EPP file:

```
<% | Hash $filter | -%>
<% include stdlib -%>
<% $filter.keys.sort.filter |$k| {$k != 'filtertype'}.each |$k| { -%>
<%= $k %>: '<%= $filter[$k] %>'
<% } -%>
```

Things to note:

1) You need `include stdlib` to access the `keys` and `sort` functions.

2) The variable name `$filter` now clashes with the built-in Puppet function `filter()`, which is syntactically fine, but confusing, so you would consider renaming the `$filter` variable to something else for clarity.

Also, if you don't care about sorting the keys, then I could make what you tried work using:

```
<% | Hash $filter | -%>
<% $filter.filter |$k| {$k[0] != 'filtertype'}.each |$k, $v| { -%>
<%= $k %>: '<%= $v %>'
<% } -%>
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387586/using-puppet-hash-for-epp-templates) where I just answered a similar question.