# key-value hash for epp template

Tags: puppet

How to porting next code from erb template to epp:

```
<%- if @mime_types -%>

# Custom additional mime types
<%- @mime_types.sort_by {|key,value| key}.each do |key,value| -%>
<%= key %> <%= value %>;
<%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

or how work with key-value hashes in epp templates. 
for example next code return error "**Invalid EPP: Syntax error at '|'**"

```
# mime.types.epp
<%- | Hash[String, String] $nginx::config::mime_types | -%>
<% include stdlib -%>
<% $nginx::config::mime_types.keys.sort.each |$key| { -%>
    <%= $key %> <%= $nginx::config::mime_types[$key] %>
<% } -%>
```

manifests:

```
# manifests/config.pp
class nginx::config {
  $mimetypes=lookup('nginx::mimetypes')
  file { "${nginx::params::conf_dir}/mime.types":
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp("${module_name}/mime.types.epp"),
  }
```

hiera:

```
nginx::mimetypes:
  video/ogg: 'ogv'
```

puppet version:

```
#puppet --version
5.0.1
```

Many thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what aspect of the problem is causing you trouble, so I'm just going to throw something out there.  If you're using EPP then I presume you are on Puppet 4 or possibly 5, or at minimum on Puppet 3.7 with the future parser enabled.  In that case you have access to Puppet's [`each()`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/function.html#each) function, which serves in the Puppet language / EPP much as various types' `each` methods do in Ruby / ERB.

Comment: This question is almost identical to the one I already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387586/using-puppet-hash-for-epp-templates?rq=1

Comment: @AlexHarvey yeap but i have some problem with use this construction. For example code `<%- | Hash[String, String] $sudo::def_users | -%>
<% include stdlib -%>
<% $sudo::def_users.keys.sort.each |$key| { -%>
Defaults:<%= $key %> <%= $sudo::def_users[$key] %>
<% } -%>` return next error: "Invalid EPP: Syntax error at '|'"

Comment: @beliy Please add that to the question. We cannot really read that in a comment.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Sorry, I'm new with few questions on this site

Comment: @beliy Also show how you are calling the EPP template from your manifest.

Comment: @AlexHarvey edited main message.

Comment: add puppet version in main message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't possible use model `$classname::subclassname::lookup_variable` in epp template for hashes

2) Need use `<%- | Hash[String, String] $mime_types | -%>` and
`<% include stdlib -%>` only on start epp template

correct files:

```
# manifests/config.pp
class nginx::config {
  $mimetypes=lookup('nginx::mimetypes')
  file { "${nginx::params::conf_dir}/mime.types":
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp("${module_name}/mime.types.epp", { mimetypes => $mimetypes }),
}

# mime.types.epp
<%- | Hash[String, String] $mimetypes | -%> # 1 line
<% include stdlib -%> # 2 line
# some code...
<% $mimetypes.keys.sort.each |$key| { -%>
    <%= $key %> <%= $mimetypes[$key] %>
<% } -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, brand new to posting, but it won't let me comment on the accepted answer...

to answer @beily question in the comments regarding `Invalid EPP: Syntax error at '|'`, i resolved this by moving `<%- | Hash[String, String] $mimetypes | -%>` to the first line of the .epp, as shown in the Puppet EPP documentation - https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_epp.html

hope this helps someone!